# Static vs. nonstatic functions in Pebble apps

Tags: c, pebble-watch

Having just started out developing for the [Pebble](http://developer.getpebble.com) app - and also returning to my very basic C skills which has not been maintained for many many years, I am trying to understand the basic structure of these Pebble apps.

I do know the difference between static and nonstatic, but would be very happy if anyone could help shed some light on the impact on my application in this case. I have pasted minimized example code below, which shows how the Pebble app is structured in the two cases.

**Static version**

```
#include <pebble.h>

static Window *window;

static void handle_init(void) {
    window = window_create();
    window_stack_push(window, true);

}

static void handle_deinit(void) {
    window_destroy(window);
}

int main(void) {
    handle_init();
    app_event_loop();
    handle_deinit();
}
```

**Non-static version**

```
#include <pebble.h>

Window *window;

void handle_init(void) {
    window = window_create();
    window_stack_push(window, true);

}

void handle_deinit(void) {
    window_destroy(window);
}

int main(void) {
    handle_init();
    app_event_loop();
    handle_deinit();
}
```

My question is this:

**What's the implications of using nonstatic vs static variables and functions?**

I have tried to find information on the Pebble developer site, but static and non-static examples seems be be used without much consistency and I have failed to find a good official guideline.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It has to do with *linkage* and *visibility*. In short, *global* symbols marked `static` are not exported from the [*translation unit*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29) (source file) it's defined in. That means if you have multiple source files in your project, if you declare a global variable or function `static` in one file, that variable or function can't be "seen" or used from any other source file.

And this is (or should be) basic C knowledge, nothing special to do with Pebble.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying - answered my question. I had a feeling this was basic C knowledge, however I was unsure whether it may be any specific pattern related to Pebble development.